# ¿Cómo se puede hacer que una función me devuelva el valor de una id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo 3 id que son: cuidad 1, cuidad 2 y cuidad 3. Estos mismos id los tienen 3 botones y quiero crear una función que me devuelva el id del botón que estoy presionando.

Comment: Hola @chris, para que podamos ayudarte debes rehacer la pregunta según marca la gúia [ask], así podremos echarte una mano. Si no conoces como funciona el sitio te recomiendo que visites el [tour], te ayudará para futuras consultas.

Answer (score 4):

usa [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) de jQuery para obtener atributos de la etiqueta, como por ejemplo el id -> `attr("id")`

```js
function devolverid(bnt){
  var id = $(bnt).attr("id");
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="boton_1" onclick="devolverid(this)">Boton 1</button>
<button id="boton_2" onclick="devolverid(this)">Boton 2</button>
<button id="boton_3" onclick="devolverid(this)">Boton 3</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una solucion usando solamente JavaScript sin librerias.

```js
// Devuelve el id del boton pulsado 
function devolverId(evento) {
  return evento.target.id;
}
```

```html
<button id="boton_1" onclick="devolverId(event)">Boton 1</button>
<button id="boton_2" onclick="devolverId(event)">Boton 2</button>
<button id="boton_3" onclick="devolverId(event)">Boton 3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí una forma sencilla agrega una clase común a cada botón luego distingues a través del this = clickeado. Luego tomas el atributo con .attr("id").

```js
$('.btnCiudad').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // id Boton clickeado
    alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="boton_1" class="btnCiudad">Boton 1</button>
<button id="boton_2" class="btnCiudad">Boton 2</button>
<button id="boton_3" class="btnCiudad">Boton 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Le puedes poner el mismo nombre a los 3 botones(con el atributo name) y hacer un listener en jQuery algo así:

```
$('button[name="nombre_del_boton"]').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    //Ponerselo a un hidden input algo así
    $('#id_de_tu_hidden').attr('id',id)

}
```